# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip

Tags: python, list, attributeerror

I cant figure out why this isnt working and just throwing me an error. I tried to move some things areounf and its still not working. It has to be something about it not reading to the list or something like that.

```
from Country import Country
import csv


class CountryIRSystem:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__list_countries = []

  def search_name (self, country_name):
    for country in self.__list_countries:
      if country.country_name == country_name:
        return country_name
    return None

  def create_info(self, country_data):

    with open(country_data, "r") as csvfile:
      csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
      for line in csvreader:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        words = line.split()

        country = Country()

        country.country_name = words[2]
        country.country_code = words[3]
        country.acc_to_clean_fuel = words[4]
        country.acc_to_elec = words[5]
        country.annual_freshwater_withdrawl = words[6]
        country.armed_forces_tot = words[7]
        country.expense_gdp = words[8]

        self.__list_countries.append(country)
```

Comment: Basically, because `line` is already a `list`. When you use the `csv.reader` you don't get the lines of text in the file. The reader will break them down for you already into "cells" of your CSV file, splitting by comma under the hood. For a regular scenario, you shouldn't need the `.strip` nor proooobably the `split` (which the way you are using it would split by whitespace, not by comma)

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader): "Each row read from the csv file is returned as a **list of strings**". You are treating the returned value as a string rather than a list of strings, even though the documentation says it's a list of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for line in csvreader:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    words = line.split()
```

`csvreader` returns a *list* of field values, not a plain line of text.

So you can just do this instead:

```
for words in csvreader:
    ...
```